# android target version is not showing higher versions

Tags: android, sdk

I have updated my sdk to version 22.but while creating new project it is not showing any higher version than 18. sdk updating was done correctly.There were no issues while downloading new versions.What should i do now?

[image]

Comment: start using android studio buddy

Comment: dear you should move to android studio look here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects